# How can I collect the user's correct choice in my Trivia game?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried multiple things to collect the right answer when the radio button is pressed, but after the game is done I still get a 0 out of 5.
I'm not sure what else to do and have been stuck on this for a while.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $("#clickStart").click(function() {
    $('#questions').show(600);
    $('#clock').show(700);
    $('#hide').hide(500);


  });


  (function() {
    var questions = [{
        question: "The great Victoria Desert is located in?",
        choices: ['Canada', 'West Africa', 'Australia', 'North America'],
        correctAnswer: 'Australia'
      },
      {
        question: "The intersecting lines drawn on maps and globes are?",
        choices: ['lattitudes', 'longitudes', 'geographic grids', 'none of the above'],
        correctAnswer: 'geographic gird'
      },
      {
        question: "The landmass of which of the following continents is the least?",
        choices: ['Africa', 'Asia', 'Australia', 'Europe'],
        correctAnswer: 'Australia'
      },
      {
        question: "Without ____ the equator would be much hotter than it is while the poles would be much cooler",
        choices: ['Lattitude of redistribution of heat', 'Cycle of air circulation', 'Global wind pattern', 'All are similiar'],
        correctAnswer: 'All are simliar'
      },
      {
        question: "The habitats valuable for commercially harvested species are called?",
        choices: ['Coral reefs', 'Sea grass bed', 'hot spots', 'None of the above'],
        correctAnswer: 'Sea grass bed'
      }
    ];

    var questionCounter = 0; //Tracks question number
    var selections = []; //Array containing user choices
    var quiz = $("#quiz"); //Quiz div object

    // Display initial question
    displayNext();

    //  'next' button
    $("#next").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      // Suspend click listener during fade animation
      if (quiz.is(":animated")) {
        return false;
      }
      choose();

      // If no user selection, progress is stopped
      if (isNaN(selections[questionCounter])) {
        alert("Please make a selection!");
      } else {
        questionCounter++;
        displayNext();
      }
    });

    // 'prev' button
    $("#prev").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      if (quiz.is(":animated")) {
        return false;
      }
      choose();
      questionCounter--;
      displayNext();
    });

    // 'Start Over' button
    $("#start").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      if (quiz.is(":animated")) {
        return false;
      }
      questionCounter = 0;
      selections = [];
      displayNext();
      $("#start").hide();
    });

    // Animates buttons on hover
    $(".button").on("mouseenter", function() {
      $(this).addClass("active");
    });
    $(".button").on("mouseleave", function() {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
    });

    // Creates and returns the div that contains the questions and
    // the answer selections
    function createQuestionElement(index) {
      var qElement = $("<div>", {
        id: "question"
      });

      var header = $("<h2>Question " + (index + 1) + ":</h2>");
      qElement.append(header);

      var question = $("<p>").append(questions[index].question);
      qElement.append(question);

      var radioButtons = createRadios(index);
      qElement.append(radioButtons);

      return qElement;
    }

    // Creates a list of the answer choices as radio inputs
    function createRadios(index) {
      var radioList = $("<ul>");
      var item;
      var input = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < questions[index].choices.length; i++) {
        item = $("<li>");
        input = '<input type="radio" name="answer" value=' + i + " />";
        input += questions[index].choices[i];
        item.append(input);
        radioList.append(item);
      }
      return radioList;
    }

    // Reads the user selection and pushes the value to an array
    function choose() {
      selections[questionCounter] = +$('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();
    }

    // Displays next requested element
    function displayNext() {
      quiz.fadeOut(function() {
        $("#question").remove();

        if (questionCounter < questions.length) {
          var nextQuestion = createQuestionElement(questionCounter);
          quiz.append(nextQuestion).fadeIn();
          if (!isNaN(selections[questionCounter])) {
            $("input[value=" + selections[questionCounter] + "]").prop(
              "checked",
              true
            );
          }

          // Controls display of 'prev' button
          if (questionCounter === 1) {
            $("#prev").show();
          } else if (questionCounter === 0) {
            $("#prev").hide();
            $("#next").show();
          }
        } else {
          var scoreElem = displayScore();
          quiz.append(scoreElem).fadeIn();
          $("#next").hide();
          $("#prev").hide();
          $("#start").show();
        }
      });
    }

    // Computes score and returns a paragraph element to be displayed
    function displayScore() {
      var score = $("<p>", {
        id: "question"
      });

      var numCorrect = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
        if (selections[i] === questions[i].correctAnswer) {
          numCorrect++;
        }
      }

      score.append(
        "You got " +
        numCorrect +
        " questions out of " +
        questions.length +
        " right!!!"
      );
      return score;
    }
  })();
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(../images/background.png);
  height: 1vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

#title {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 7%;
}

.start-button {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  margin-top: 5%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

.start-button:hover {
  background-color: #0246e2;
  color: #f5684f;
  font-size: 50px;
}

button {
  text-align: center;
}

#clock {
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 100px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#quiz {
  text-indent: 10px;
}

.button {
  border: 4px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  color: black;
  margin: 0 2px 0 2px;
}

.button.active {
  background-color: #F8F8FF;
  color: #525252;
}

#questions {
  display: none;
  padding-top: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.button a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 25px 40px 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  border: 4px solid #B0E0E6;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
  height: 500px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#prev {
  display: none;
}

#start {
  display: none;
  width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Trivia Game</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="hide" class="row">
        <div id="header" class="text-center col-12-lg">
          <h1>How Well Do You Know Your Geography?</h1>
          <p>You have 2 min to guess all the questions...Good Luck!</p>
          <button id="clickStart" class="start-button">Start!</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="clock" class="row">
        <div class="col-12-lg text-center" id="display">
          <h3>00:00</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="questions" class="row">
        <div class="col-12-lg">
          <div id='content'>
            <br/>
            <div id='quiz'></div>
            <div class='button' id='next'><a href='#'>Next</a></div>
            <div class='button' id='prev'><a href='#'>Prev</a></div>
            <div class='button' id='start'> <a href='#'>Start Over</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>





    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/app.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
function choose() {
  selections[questionCounter] = +$('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();
}
```

The value of the input is its index. So index===correctAnswer will fail.
You either do:

```
if (questions[i].choices[selections[i]] === questions[i].correctAnswer) {
          numCorrect++;
}
```

or you store the index in correctAnswer...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  $("#clickStart").click(function() {
    $('#questions').show(600);
    $('#clock').show(700);
    $('#hide').hide(500);


  });


  (function() {
    var questions = [{
        question: "The great Victoria Desert is located in?",
        choices: ['Canada', 'West Africa', 'Australia', 'North America'],
        correctAnswer: 'Australia'
      },
      {
        question: "The intersecting lines drawn on maps and globes are?",
        choices: ['lattitudes', 'longitudes', 'geographic grids', 'none of the above'],
        correctAnswer: 'geographic gird'
      },
      {
        question: "The landmass of which of the following continents is the least?",
        choices: ['Africa', 'Asia', 'Australia', 'Europe'],
        correctAnswer: 'Australia'
      },
      {
        question: "Without ____ the equator would be much hotter than it is while the poles would be much cooler",
        choices: ['Lattitude of redistribution of heat', 'Cycle of air circulation', 'Global wind pattern', 'All are similiar'],
        correctAnswer: 'All are simliar'
      },
      {
        question: "The habitats valuable for commercially harvested species are called?",
        choices: ['Coral reefs', 'Sea grass bed', 'hot spots', 'None of the above'],
        correctAnswer: 'Sea grass bed'
      }
    ];

    var questionCounter = 0; //Tracks question number
    var selections = []; //Array containing user choices
    var quiz = $("#quiz"); //Quiz div object

    // Display initial question
    displayNext();

    //  'next' button
    $("#next").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      // Suspend click listener during fade animation
      if (quiz.is(":animated")) {
        return false;
      }
      choose();

      // If no user selection, progress is stopped
      if (isNaN(selections[questionCounter])) {
        alert("Please make a selection!");
      } else {
        questionCounter++;
        displayNext();
      }
    });

    // 'prev' button
    $("#prev").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      if (quiz.is(":animated")) {
        return false;
      }
      choose();
      questionCounter--;
      displayNext();
    });

    // 'Start Over' button
    $("#start").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      if (quiz.is(":animated")) {
        return false;
      }
      questionCounter = 0;
      selections = [];
      displayNext();
      $("#start").hide();
    });

    // Animates buttons on hover
    $(".button").on("mouseenter", function() {
      $(this).addClass("active");
    });
    $(".button").on("mouseleave", function() {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
    });

    // Creates and returns the div that contains the questions and
    // the answer selections
    function createQuestionElement(index) {
      var qElement = $("<div>", {
        id: "question"
      });

      var header = $("<h2>Question " + (index + 1) + ":</h2>");
      qElement.append(header);

      var question = $("<p>").append(questions[index].question);
      qElement.append(question);

      var radioButtons = createRadios(index);
      qElement.append(radioButtons);

      return qElement;
    }

    // Creates a list of the answer choices as radio inputs
    function createRadios(index) {
      var radioList = $("<ul>");
      var item;
      var input = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < questions[index].choices.length; i++) {
        item = $("<li>");
        input = '<input type="radio" name="answer" value=' + i + " />";
        input += questions[index].choices[i];
        item.append(input);
        radioList.append(item);
      }
      return radioList;
    }

    // Reads the user selection and pushes the value to an array
    function choose() {
      selections[questionCounter] = +$('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();
    }

    // Displays next requested element
    function displayNext() {
      quiz.fadeOut(function() {
        $("#question").remove();

        if (questionCounter < questions.length) {
          var nextQuestion = createQuestionElement(questionCounter);
          quiz.append(nextQuestion).fadeIn();
          if (!isNaN(selections[questionCounter])) {
            $("input[value=" + selections[questionCounter] + "]").prop(
              "checked",
              true
            );
          }

          // Controls display of 'prev' button
          if (questionCounter === 1) {
            $("#prev").show();
          } else if (questionCounter === 0) {
            $("#prev").hide();
            $("#next").show();
          }
        } else {
          var scoreElem = displayScore();
          quiz.append(scoreElem).fadeIn();
          $("#next").hide();
          $("#prev").hide();
          $("#start").show();
        }
      });
    }

    // Computes score and returns a paragraph element to be displayed
    function displayScore() {
      var score = $("<p>", {
        id: "question"
      });

      var numCorrect = 0;
      console.log(selections.map((el,i)=>questions[i].choices[el]),questions.map(e=>e.correctAnswer));
      for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++) {
        if (questions[i].choices[selections[i]] === questions[i].correctAnswer) {
          numCorrect++;
        }
      }

      score.append(
        "You got " +
        numCorrect +
        " questions out of " +
        questions.length +
        " right!!!"
      );
      return score;
    }
  })();
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(../images/background.png);
  height: 1vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

#title {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 7%;
}

.start-button {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  margin-top: 5%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

.start-button:hover {
  background-color: #0246e2;
  color: #f5684f;
  font-size: 50px;
}

button {
  text-align: center;
}

#clock {
  display: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 100px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#quiz {
  text-indent: 10px;
}

.button {
  border: 4px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 40px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  color: black;
  margin: 0 2px 0 2px;
}

.button.active {
  background-color: #F8F8FF;
  color: #525252;
}

#questions {
  display: none;
  padding-top: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.button a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 25px 40px 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  border: 4px solid #B0E0E6;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
  height: 500px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#prev {
  display: none;
}

#start {
  display: none;
  width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Trivia Game</title>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="hide" class="row">
        <div id="header" class="text-center col-12-lg">
          <h1>How Well Do You Know Your Geography?</h1>
          <p>You have 2 min to guess all the questions...Good Luck!</p>
          <button id="clickStart" class="start-button">Start!</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="clock" class="row">
        <div class="col-12-lg text-center" id="display">
          <h3>00:00</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="questions" class="row">
        <div class="col-12-lg">
          <div id='content'>
            <br/>
            <div id='quiz'></div>
            <div class='button' id='next'><a href='#'>Next</a></div>
            <div class='button' id='prev'><a href='#'>Prev</a></div>
            <div class='button' id='start'> <a href='#'>Start Over</a></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>





    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/app.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
selections[questionCounter] = +$('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();
```

Do you mean +=, not = + ?

Answer (score 0):

No, I was just being dumb and calling the string of the array rather than the number.  So instead of having the correct answer be 'Austrailia', it would be 2.  As soon as I posted this question, of course, I figure it out lol.  Thanks for the help anyways though.